# Facebook API Error code 100 - Unity

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a game with Unity3D for Android. I'm using Facebook App for sharing game score in Facebook. But I receive a error message ;

[image]

My codes are here ;

```
//facebook share start
public static void share(string link, string pictureLink, string name,string caption, string description, string redirectUri){
    Application.OpenURL(ShareUrl +
                        "?app_id=" + AppId +
                        "&amp;link=" + WWW.EscapeURL( link )+
                        "&amp;picture=" + WWW.EscapeURL(pictureLink) +
                        "&amp;name=" + WWW.EscapeURL(name) +
                        "&amp;caption=" + WWW.EscapeURL(caption) +
                        "&amp;description=" + WWW.EscapeURL(description) +
                        "&amp;redirect_uri=" + WWW.EscapeURL(redirectUri));
}//facebook share end
if(GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width/2,(Screen.height/2-30),80,20), "Share")){
            print("Share");
            share("http://www.halilcosgun.com","https://24.media.tumblr.com/avatar_ce3a5b939737_64.png","Facebook skor paylaşma denemesi " + score,"Skor da mı paylaşmıyah?","oyun çok yakında!","http://facebook.com");
        }
```

I tried to write many adresses (many many configurations) intead of "http://facebook.com", but I can't find the true one. 
If you know the solution, can you halp me please?

I would like to thank you for your interest.

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to make use of official Unity Facebook SDK?

Comment: Replace `&amp;` with `&`?

Answer (score 0):

there must me an invalid parameter that you have provided . try to find it out and make the change it will solve your issue

try the share with first s in caps example

```
        Share("http://www.halilcosgun.com","https://24.media.tumblr.com/avatar_ce3a5b939737_64.png","Facebook skor paylaşma denemesi " + score,"Skor da mı paylaşmıyah?","oyun çok yakında!","http://facebook.com");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Ashan, but I'm still receive the error message.